# Как в циклической карусели изменить у центрального элемента прозрачность?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, карусель

Есть зацикленная карусель `owl carousel 2` у которой элементы изначально полупрозрачные, а при наведении становятся непрозрачными. Хочу сделать так, чтобы независимо от количества элементов в карусели центральный блок был всегда непрозрачным. Пробовал это сделать через `:nth-child()`, но проблема в том, что в зацикленной карусели создаются дополнительные клонированные блоки и не получается сделать центральный элемент непрозрачным - что можно предпринять?
[фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/rtvc5exr/4/)

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    autoWidth: true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:2000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        },
        868: {
            items: 2
        },
        1040: {
            items: 3
        },
        1300: {
            items: 4,
            margin: 20
        },
        3070: {
            items: 5,
            margin: 20
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.item {
    width: 185px;
}
.owl-carousel .item {
    height: 10rem;
    background: #4DC7A0;
    padding: 1rem;
    opacity:0.3;
}
.owl-carousel .item.active:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity:1;
}
  .owl-carousel .item:hover {
      opacity:1;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
        <h4>1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>4</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>5</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>6</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>7</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>8</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>9</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>10</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>11</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>12</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вроде как у центрального блока, который является активным, есть особый класс а-ля `active` - ему и надо прописать насильно непрозрачность

Comment: @lexxl попытка хорошая, но не только у одного элемента класс `active` и он по какому-то алгоритму яменяется

Comment: ну блин. если выполнить код из вопроса, то будет 4 блока с классом `active`. если нужно второму задать стиль, то `.active:nth-of-type(2)`. не?

Comment: @lexxl не знаю, вроде задаю так, как вы пишете, но блок не становится непрозрачным.. https://jsfiddle.net/rtvc5exr/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо было для `.center > div` придавать нужные свойства :

```
.owl-item.center > div {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Дэмо : https://jsfiddle.net/Geyan/rtvc5exr/6/

Comment: да, отлично - супер!